# Why my chart works on IPhone/IPad but not on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, charts, cordova, enyo

---

Hi all,

I'm using Enyo with JS. I've used PhoneGap to portate my code to IOs - IPhone/IPad. But the chart is not working on Android.. The problem is that the chart doesn't render. I've been looked and find some people saying that SVG charts doesn't work on android Apps.. but I'm using a jquery float type.
  Well, if its necessary more information or details, please fill free to ask.. 
Thanks..

Here is LogCat error:

> 06-06 09:24:29.093: V/webview(3910):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  >FASLE 
>   06-06 09:24:30.593: V/webview(3910):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
>   06-06 09:24:30.921: V/webview(3910):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
>   06-06 09:24:32.007: V/webview(3910):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
>   06-06 09:24:33.398: V/webview(3910):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
>   06-06 09:24:36.125: V/webview(3910):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
>   06-06 09:24:37.640: V/webview(3910):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
>   06-06 09:24:39.867: V/webview(3910):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
>   **06-06 09:24:40.406: D/CordovaLog(3910): Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 720, height = 0
>   06-06 09:24:40.406: E/Web Console(3910): Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 720, height = 0 at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.flot.js:118
>   06-06 09:24:40.421: D/CordovaLog(3910): Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 720, height = 0
>   06-06 09:24:40.421: E/Web Console(3910): Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 720, height = 0 at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.flot.js:118**

Any ideas?

Comment: One detail: the container is not finding the height of the chart. What not occurs on IOs or in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

I added an 'if' statement inside the method that creates the graph. In this 'if', the height found (zero) is multiplied by the percentage required for the size of the chart (in decimal).

> if (document.height == 0) {
>      height = document.height * 0.5;
>   }

Comment: Doesn't that still yield height = 0?

Comment: Hi, Yes, still in zero. But was the only way that I found to contour the problem. If you have any other ideas, please post! :D

Comment: You might need to throw the chart (or your app) into a fittable row/column and set the fit:true on the chart/main area.  Or, you could try explicitly setting your height on one of the containers.